# How to pass a variable to another namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have to pass a count value to another `namespace` here. I have 2 classes `Select.cs` and `Value.cs`. `Select.cs` has the following code:

```
    public bool Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        string strinvselect = string.Format("select * from newlog where
                              pass='{0}'", Password);

        DataTable dtlog = ExecuteStatement(strinvselect);

        if (dtlog.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            string strvalue = string.Format("Select * FROM login WHERE uid= 
                                           '{0}'", UserName);

            DataTable newlogin = ExecuteStatement(strvalue);

            try
            {
                if (newlogin.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    loginStatus = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                loginStatus = false;
            }

            return loginStatus;
        }
    }
```

I have to create a count value `if(newlogin.Rows.Count == 1)`, `count=1` and this value should be available in Value.cs to check a functionality.
In `Value.cs` a function `getdetails()` is called. Here I need to check

```
        if (count == 1)
        {
            getdetails();
        }
        else
        {
            // call another function
        }
```

Comment: You want to pass count to to the Value.cs? Possible post your Value.cs code here.

Comment: First, a little lesson in terminology:  You don't pass *anything* to a namespace.  Namespaces are just containers for classes.  You can pass *things* to Methods.  You can assign *things* to Properties, Fields, and Variables.

Comment: Additionally, `Select.cs` and `Value.cs` are filenames, not classes.

Comment: And finally - HUH?  Even after adjusting for your terminology, you don't make-a the sense.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reinvent both ASP.NET's authentication and profile mechanisms? Why don't you just use what's out of the box? These are faster and especially *safer* than hand-coding your own versions, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Namespaces are not really relevant here, the issue is that you need to access the variable from a different class. The way you have "global" variables that are specific to the user is the Session, so store the value in a Session variable and have your other class access the Session variable.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["myData"] = "somevalue";
```

Value function

```
string x;

if (Session["myData"] == null)
{
   // handle the data not being set
}
else
{
   x = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["myData"].ToString(); ;
}
```

Comment: The question and the answer have no relation between them. It's still unclear just *what* you are asking. Session variables are *neither* global variables *nor* user-specific containers and should *never* be used like this. Session variables are per user **session**, which means they are volatile and they expire. It also means they have to be serialized, they can't store a lot of data and they don't scale.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for query for count outside Login ( basically wherever you need it ) then pass it as "username + count" (you will need to split it) to login first parameter as you can avoid checking count inside Login again.